# Loging out of Azure Passport authentication Node js

Tags: node.js, azure, passport.js

I have a node js application in which we have used azure login with passport authentication.

I have successfully logged in using azure and the application is working fine.

But, when I logged out and give the url to a page - it checks for authentication and automatically go to that page without asking for login.

Once I logged in my url contains below query string
1. session_state
2. code
3. state
4. token

Log in Code:

```
app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect: '/' }), function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
```

});

Logout code:

```
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.session.destroy();
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

When i logout the page redirects to my index page. Then when i give '/login' to the url it takes me to the page without going to logging in page

Please help to get out of this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is caused by the Authorization Code Grant Flow of OAuth 2.0. Something like that there are any session on Azure AD OAuth 2.0 service. It is not the problem of `passportjs` or `expressjs`.

We can have the following simple test, visit the authentication endpoint in browser, `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token%20code&client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&response_mode=query&scope=openid`

You will need to fill the email and password first, after you finishing the login flow, the second time you visit the endpoint, you will not longer need to fill the email or password anymore.

We can set the url param **`prompt`** to **`login`** in the authorize endpoint to force the users to re-authenticate every time.

You can refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx#code-snippet-3 for the details.

But in the azure passport oidcstrategy, we should modify the source code for add the param into the endpoint.

After you install the `passport-azure-ad` module, open the file `/node_modules/passport-azure-ad/lib/passport-azure-ad/oidcstrategy.js`, at Line 545 (more or less), you can find the following code snippet:

```
      var params = {};
      if (self.authorizationParams) { params = self.authorizationParams(options); }
      params['response_type'] = config.responseType;
      log.info('We are sending the response_type: ', params['response_type']);
      params['client_id'] = config.clientID;
      params['redirect_uri'] = callbackURL;
      ...
```

We can add the sentence `params['prompt'] = 'login';` following the code snippet to add the support.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

### edit

> Is there any way to prompt login only when i logged out...

I am not sure that do you mean, you want to check the user is authenticated when he visit `login` route, if is, do not prompt login flow?

If so, you can custom a middleware to check the authenticated. E.G.:

```
function checkAuthenticatedOnLogin(req,res,next){
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) { 
    return next(); 
  }else{
    res.send('do not need login');
  }
}

app.get('/login',checkAuthenticatedOnLogin,
  passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect',{ failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    log.info('Login was called in the Sample');
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: Thank u.. Now its prompting for the login every time... Is there any way to prompt login only when i logged out... currently it is prompting for login when i logged in and go to the login page again... It has to redirect to other page...

Comment: updated, please check whether it's your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Logging out of your application does not mean the user is logged out of Azure. When a user logs out of your application you simply destroy the session your application has for said user. When they go to login again it will redirect them to Azure (where they're still logged, and where your application still has permission) which then instantly redirects back to your application with a token for that user. You would need to have the user log out of Azure to have them prompted again for their credentials.

Comment: OK.. Is it possible to logout of Azure too.. Is there any reference or tutorial on this..

Answer (score 1):

1) I had this same problem, as passpor-azure documented I was executing this function to logout:

```
 logout: function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
  }
```

But Azure login session keeps active, so when I re-enter into my website, the autentication request will automatically be valid and no login page will be showned.

I tried @Gary Liu - MSFT suggestion to configure *prompt:login* option, but has @user3211705 commented, this makes login page reappear (even if I don't do logout and I have a portal.azure.com tab open), for instance when I restart my server (note: this isn't wrong, but when we are developing, one restarts the server all the time, and it gets annoying to login all the time)

2) Part of my solution came from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463426/azure-web-app-logout-from-aad-authentication):

Which suggest to invoke this url to logout user at Azure AD:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tennantid>/oauth2/logout
```

But only doing this didn't do the job for all situations.

If I have my website open in more than one window/tab browser, the user gets invalid in Azure AD by invoking this url, but I can keep using my website at the other tab (it seems like the user in that tab session keeps still active).

This is similar to have my website in one tab and on another tab with the portal.azure.com open, and do logout in portal.azure.com which invalidate my user at Azure AD.

So my final solution was a mix of both

```
 logout: function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tennantid>/oauth2/logout');
  }
```

This does logout my user in the request and invokes logout authentication in Azure AD.

One can still add a redirect uri at logout url param **?post_logout_redirect_uri=**

```
/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=<your website>
```

Comment: Note: <your website> must be in the list of approved reply URLs in the azure application config.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for [Azure xplat](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli) they don't seem to call an explicit logout function, instead they simply delete all of the relevant client side tokens.

If there are no local tokens you can't be logged in!

Comment: I tried to clear local storage like id_token, session_state, state and code... but still it is not logging out... Is there any other to clear manually in azure??

Answer (score 0):

Azure Passport doesn't have logout as of now. MSAL helped me however, MSAL doesn't expose accounts. You can try the following:

```
logout(options = {}) {
        return (req, res, next) => {
            const accessToken = req.session?.accessToken
            if (accessToken) {
                let logoutUri = `${this.msalConfig.auth.authority}/oauth2/v2.0/`;

                if (options.postLogoutRedirectUri) {
                    logoutUri += `logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=${options.postLogoutRedirectUri}`;
                }
                res.redirect(logoutUri);
            } else {
                return res.redirect("/login");
            }
        }
    }
```

This worked for me. This will take you to the sign-out of the Microsoft page and you can choose the account you wish to logout from.