# Azure Web App logout from AAD Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

i am unable to logout from my simple azure web app that has Azure active directory as the authentication provider.

the user logs into the site using the AAD login page shown [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-get-started-2/#authenticate-your-users)

but i am struggling to find out how to log the user out.

i tried using the various undocumented logout urls like

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tennantid>/oauth2/logout
```

although they report the the user is logged out, it isnt. As returning to the previous URL goes straight thru without a sign page.

i am guessing there are some cookies that need to be cleared but where on earth is all this stuff documented?

any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Did you try "<your-doman>/.auth/logout" in the browser?

Comment: In my case just _signInManager.SignOutAsync() is needed.

Comment: @prakash nope. but i when i did, it worked exactly as i expected. I am happy to accept your post as an answer. thanks very much. where is this documented?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you try "[your-domain]/.auth/logout"?

I too had a very hard time figuring this out and I found it in the comments of this [blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: @prakash I had a same issue now. My login url is https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect and logout url is https://token.botframework.com/.auth/logout but still not logging out the user. As a result when a next time login it does shows me the list of accounts to select. Please help