# How to do Single Sign-Out SAML using passport-saml npm package?

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, passport.js, saml-2.0, passport-saml

The application using single sign on flow in Azure AD using the npm package [passport-saml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-saml).

Application built in nodejs express framework.

passport saml Configuration looks like this snippet:

filename - config.js

```
passport: {
    strategy: 'saml',
    saml: {
        path: process.env.SAML_PATH ,
        entryPoint: process.env.SAML_ENTRY_POINT || 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/saml2',
        issuer: 'app id',
        cert: process.env.SAML_CERT,
        callbackUrl: "https://application_url/login/callback",
        logoutUrl: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/saml2',
    }
}
```

**In the above config entry point & logoutUrl is same.**

Code snippet for express app which consumes passport SAML strategy to connect Azure AD.

filename - connect.js:

```
const SamlStrategy = require('passport-saml').Strategy;
const config = require('./config.js');

app.use(passport.initialize())
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user);
    });
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user);
    });

passport.use(new SamlStrategy(config.passport.saml,
function (req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    
}
))

/*express app router*/

app.get("/login", (req, res, next) => {
     passport.authenticate(config.passport.strategy, { failureRedirect: "/" })(req, res, next);
})

app.post('/login/callback', (req, res, next)=> {
 /*processing logic after the successful auth from Azure AD SAML*/
})
```

Up to this point it's possible to do SAML auth in Azure AD and received the login callback as well. Note: Login callback properly configured in Redirect URI's of Azure AD application.

Moving on, having a problem in performing logout on an express app router.

LogoutUrl is configured in Azure AD application settings
[image: Azure logout-url screenshot]

Whenever app hits movelogout route and it needs to logout Azure Ad session. How it's possible to issue a logout request to Azure AD inside this route using passport-saml strategy?

Code continues
filename: connect.js

```
  app.get('/movelogout', (req, res, next)=> {
    //How to issue logout request ?
      
 })

/*Callback for successful logout in Azure AD*/
app.post('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
     //Do post logout operation
})
```

In the nutshell, I have been trying to accomplish [Azure Single sign out SAML protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-out-saml-protocol#logoutrequest) using passport-saml. The link having SAML logout request and it's not having explanation in javascript way of issuing SAML request.

I am not quite sure with relation between logoutUrl in config & front-end logout Url in Azure setting.

Any suggestions or solutions to perform Azure AD session logout manually are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> //How to issue logout request ?

Passport manifest a `logout()` function on `req` , that can be called from any route handler which needs to terminate a login session. Invoking `logout()` will also remove the `req.user` property and clear the login session (if any).
You can try adding following cmd to `Logout` in your `connect.js` file

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Or,

```
app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
    req.session.destroy();
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

> relation between logoutUrl in config & front-end logout Url in Azure
> setting.

Based on this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-sign-in?tabs=nodejs) No front channel  Logout   URL is needed while registering the application in Node.js.

[image]

For more information please refer the below links:-

.[Microsoft Azure Active Directory Passport.js Plug-In | Git-Hub](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) .

.[Logging out of Azure Passport authentication Node js | SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054116/loging-out-of-azure-passport-authentication-node-js) .